# Como definir Enumeration em JSON

Tags: json, rest, wsdl

Tenho o seguinte enumeration em XSD para um WSDL

```
<xsd:simpleType name="tipoDocumento">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="INICIAL"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="FINAL"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="JUSTIFICATIVA"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

estou convertendo o mesmo para JSON

Como eu defino o enumeration acima em uma interface JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON é um formato de mensagem como o XML. Já o XSD (Schema Definition) é um formato utilizado para moldar e validar uma estrutura em XML.

Para o JSON existem alguns padrões de reconhecimento / validação da estrutura, por exemplo:

- [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) - similar ao XSD para validação e reconhecimento de estruturas JSON
- [Swagger](https://swagger.io/): notação para desenhar uma API REST e nela podem ser especificas as estruturas de entrada e saída
- [RAML](https://raml.org/) - outra notação para especificar o contrato de uma API REST

Comment: Muito interessante obrigado

Answer (score 0):

JSON não é um formato rico em sintaxe para indicar diversas semânticas. Ele deixa isso para quem for interpretá-lo, que seja responsável o suficiente para interpretar de maneira correta. O JSON só manda informação de um lado para o outro.

Como depende muito do lado do leitor, você tem muitas opções de como fazer isso. Uma dessas opções é:

```
{
    'tipoDocumento': ['INICIAL', 'FINAL', 'JUSTIFICATIVA']
}
```